# How do I show the following set is closed in $R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

The set $A=\{x \in R_{+}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1\}$ is closed.

I've taken some sequence of points $(y_i) \subset A$ such that $y_i \to x$. I know I have to show $\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i=1$, I just don't know how though.

Following up on the hints:

$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is continuous, then $f(x)= f(\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i)=\lim_{i \to \infty} f(y_i) = 1$.

Any hints as to how to show it is bounded also?

Comment: Limit of a (finite) sum is the sum of the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ is continuous.

Added: The set $A$ is not bounded if $n\ge 2$.  For we can take $x_1$ large positive, $x_2=-x_1+1$, and the rest $0$.

More: The question has been modified, with the $x_i$ now non-negative. How the change affects things is dealt with in comments below.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also tell me how to show this set is bounded?

Comment: You are welcome. I am adding a remark about boundedness.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, the entries in each tuple are positive. I should've written $R_{+}^n$ in the definition of $A$. Now it is corrected.

Comment: **Positive** changes everything! For one thing, then the set $A$ is not closed, though if instead you write **non-negative**, then it is closed. And the set $A$ becomes bounded, for then all the $x_i$ are between $0$ and $1$, and a crude bound for the distance of a point in $A$ from the origin is $\sqrt{n}$ (pne can do much better).

Comment: I meant non-negative. I see that this forces each $x_i$ to be in $[0, 1]$. I don't follow how you get the bound, though.

Comment: Each $x_i$ is between $0$ and $1$, so the distance from $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to the origin is $\le \sqrt{1^2+1^2+\cdots+1^2}$, which is $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.